# Binary string such that always at least as many 0s as 1s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, catalan-numbers

**Problem**: Find the number of binary strings of length $10$ with $5$ ones and $5$ zeros such that, at any given point in the string (reading from left to right), there has appeared at least as many $0$s as $1$s.

One initial observation is that the string must start with a $0$ and end with a $1$. But from here I'm pretty much stuck. I tried several methods of cases (e.g. what happens if it starts with $01$ or $00$ or $010$ etc.) One might realize that in the first $5$ digits, at least $3$ have to be $0$s, which means that one could try all possible combinations of the first $5$ digits with $3$ zeros, $4$ zeros and $5$ zeros (with $5$ zeros there is for example only one possible combination for the whole string, for $4$ zeros there are $4^2 = 16$ possible $10$-strings)

I also tried switching $0$s for $-1$s and try to see which combinations always kept the sum of the first $n$ numbers negative, but didn't make much progress... Any help would be much appreciated :)

P.S I realize that there is an easy brute force method, but is there a cleverer solution that could be used with  longer strings?

Comment: See catalan numbers.

Comment: As you said, such a string $S$ must start with a $0$. Now consider the first (leftmost) $1$ after which the number of $0$'s and $1$'s becomes equal. Suppose that $S=0S_11S_2$, where $S_1$ is the string between the first $0$ and the $1$ described above, and $S_2$ is the string after this $1$. Try to show that $S_1$ and $S_2$ satisfy the same properties as $S$.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the number of [Dyck words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) of length $2n$ for $n=5$. These numbers are the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $C_n$. For $n=5$, meaning 10 digits, we have $C_5= 42$.

Comment: Nice! Having never heard of "dyck words" before, I naturally wonder if there is a simpler solution... the original problem was to find the probability that any given 10-string with 5 ones and 5 zeros is a dyck word, so my approach was to count the number of dyck words (and how many ways one word could be formed) and then divide by the $10!$ permutations of the string... so maybe there is a simpler solution to that problem?

Comment: @MartinWestin There are not 10! permutations of 5 1's and 5 0's. Much less.

Comment: @coffeemath I meant that the amount of permutations of any $n$-string is $n!$, regardless of what kind of string it is. I meant that there are 42 dyck words, which is then multiplied by the number of ways to get each word (which is equal to $(5!)^2 = 14400$) and then divide by the TOTAL number of permutations ($10!$) to get $\frac{42*14400}{10!} = \frac{1}{6}$, which makes sense to me

Comment: @MartinWestin Yes I just did things differently. I also got 1/6 just a different calculation of 42/C(10,5).

Comment: @MartinWestin The _number_ of permutations.